# Dates in Java, how to manipulate the year?

Tags: java, date

I have a Date object in Java. Sometimes the date's year is set to 17. When I go to output it using a SimpleDateFormat, it gets printed out as 0017. All my years are going to be in the 2000's. Is there a way to check if the year is belowe a certain value and then add 2000 to it if it is? Then once you do that, how do you recreate the Date object to use the new year? Seems like everything in the Date object is deprecated.

Comment: Are you against using Calendar for some reason?

Answer (score 3):

I would use a Calendar:

```
Date myDate = new Date();
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(myDate);
int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
if(year < 2000)
    cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, 2000); // add two thousand years
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use Calendar or Joda Time (a better choice) you can get and set the year (or other fields)

Your year shouldn't be 17 in the first place.  I would try to correct the problem at source rather than patch it later.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Date.getYear returns CurrentYear - 1900, not 2000, and it looks like you'll want to do that increment every time.

But since it's deprecated, you shouldn't use it in the first place, if possible. The API recommends you use the calendar class instead: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

If by `Date` you mean `java.util.Date`, that terribly designed class in now obsolete, years ago supplanted by the *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Convert to its replacement, [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html), using new methods added to the old classes.

```
Instant instant = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant() ;
```

Both `Instant` and `java.util.Date` represent a moment in UTC. For any given moment, both time-of-day and date vary around the globe by zone. If you want to see the date through the wall-clock time of a particular time zone, apply [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html) to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

```
ZoneID z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;
ZonedDatetTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Now interrogate for the year.

```
int year = zdt.getYear() ;
```

Adjust. If that date in the different year is not valid (February 29 in non leap year), the `ZonedDateTime` class adjusts.

```
if( year < 1000 ) {
    zdt = zdt.withYear( year + 2000 ) ; // You might also want to check for negative numbers. I'll omit that from this demo.
}
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).